# Generate sheets based Excel column value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am not an expert on excel vba, but need to assistance with it.

I have an excel worksheet currently with two sheets

1. "Datas" sheet : All my long list of [data (click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Lr1.jpg) is here.
2. "Template" sheet. A [template (click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2KyD.jpg) i created to format my data

I know this is going to be bulky.

I need a macro, or button that

1. can create a new sheet based on the template above for each line in the Column A value in "Datas" sheet
2. the name of the new sheet will be taken from the Column A value in "Datas" sheet
3. The new sheet should retain the formatting of the template after data has been copied

In summary it should look somewhat like this
[this (click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikxU8.jpg) for the first line in column A of Datas sheet
and [this (click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UyEj.jpg) for the second line in column A of Datas Sheet.
Here is a sample of the worksheet uploaded on
https://ufile.io/bxwo6

I have infact tried the following

http://sites.madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/parse-functions/sheet1-to-sheets

## PART 2 - Parse New Data To New Sheets (macro)

It did the job of taking each line and split it into different sheets. The results are
[This is my Data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKtL7.png)
[This is the result of the split which is good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujiUt.jpg)

I am somehow stuck on how to make it adapt to my template formatting.

I would be grateful if you could provide any tip, help or suggestion that i can try

Many Thanks

UPDATE:
I have tried the following code. create a copy of the template and rename it according to the value in Column A from the source

```
Sub AutoAddSheet()

    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Datas").Range("A1")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Create a new worksheet as a copy of Sheet number 9 in this example
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'Renames the new worksheets
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

UPDATE 2: This is the code that i modified from the link above. Note we cannot rename the sheets using column ":" value therefore, i modified my source by changing it from 1:1 into 1, 1:2 into 2

```
Option Explicit
Sub ParseItems()

    Dim LR As Long, Itm As Long, MyCount As Long, vCol As Long, iCol As Long, NR As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, MyArr As Variant, vTitles As String, TitleRow As Long, Append As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Column to evaluate from, column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
       vCol = 1
     
    'Sheet with data in it
       Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    'option to append new data below old data
    If MsgBox(" If sheet exists already, add new data to the bottom?" & vbLf & _
               "(if no, new data will replace old data)", _
               vbYesNo, "Append new Data?") = vbYes Then Append = True
    'Range where titles are across top of data, as string, data MUST
    'have titles in this row, edit to suit your titles locale
        vTitles = "A1:Z1"
        TitleRow = Range(vTitles).Cells(1).Row

    'Spot bottom row of data
       LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'Get a temporary list of unique values from vCol
        iCol = ws.Columns.Count
        ws.Cells(1, iCol) = "key"
        
        For Itm = TitleRow + 1 To LR
            On Error Resume Next
            If ws.Cells(Itm, vCol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction _
                .Match(ws.Cells(Itm, vCol), ws.Columns(iCol), 0) = 0 Then
                   ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(Itm, vCol)
            End If
        Next Itm
    'Sort the temporary list
        ws.Columns(iCol).Sort Key1:=ws.Cells(2, iCol), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    'Put list into an array for looping
        MyArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose _
            (ws.Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))

    'clear temporary list
        ws.Columns(iCol).Clear

    'Turn on the autofilter
        ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter

    'Loop through list one value at a time
    'The array includes the title cell, so we start at the second value in the array
        For Itm = 2 To UBound(MyArr)
            ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=CStr(MyArr(Itm))
        
            If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & CStr(MyArr(Itm)) & "'!A1)") Then   'create sheet if needed
                Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = CStr(MyArr(Itm))
                NR = 1
            Else                                                            'if it exists already
                Sheets(CStr(MyArr(Itm))).Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)   'ordering the sheets
                If Append Then                                              'find next empty row
                    NR = Sheets(CStr(MyArr(Itm))).Cells(Rows.Count, vCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Else
                    Sheets(CStr(MyArr(Itm))).Cells.Clear                    'clear data if not appending
                    NR = 1
                End If
            End If
        
            If NR = 1 Then                                                  'copy titles and data
                ws.Range("A" & TitleRow & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(CStr(MyArr(Itm))).Range("A" & NR)
            Else                                                            'copy data only
                ws.Range("A" & TitleRow + 1 & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(CStr(MyArr(Itm))).Range("A" & NR)
            End If
            
            ws.Range(vTitles).AutoFilter Field:=vCol                        'reset the autofilter
            If Append And NR > 1 Then NR = NR - 1
            MyCount = MyCount + Sheets(CStr(MyArr(Itm))).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - NR
            Sheets(CStr(MyArr(Itm))).Columns.AutoFit
        Next Itm
        
    'Cleanup
        ws.Activate
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        MsgBox "Rows with data: " & (LR - TitleRow) & vbLf & "Rows copied to other sheets: " _
                    & MyCount & vbLf & "Hope they match!!"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please understand that this is not a free coding service where you just say what you need and get it for free. People are here to help others with specific issues they have with their own code but they won't do all the work for you. So please provide the code you already have and tell what is going wrong, where you got stuck or what error messages you get and where. If you don't have anything yet start on your own and come back with your code and ask a specific question to it. Also read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Dear Peh, thanks, i have not assume this. i apologize if my writings appear like that. Infact i tried something. I have updated my post. thanks

Comment: I guess the code you use is not **exactly** the code provided in the link, right? So please provide the **exact** code **you** use. Even little changes do matter. Without looking at the code, the way to go would be: Loop through the source data and for every row do the following: (1) copy the template worksheet, (2) rename it, (3) fill in the data from the source row. So I guess you are already up the wrong tree because you started splitting up the data first, but you should start copying the template and fill in the data into that copy.

Comment: I have been able to do (1) and (2) using the following code below. It copies the template and rename it. 

Sub AutoAddSheet()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Datas").Range("A1")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Create a new worksheet as a copy of Sheet number 9 in this example
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'Renames the new worksheets
Next MyCell
End Sub


However i am still playing send the data from the source to the template

Comment: Please don't post code in comments we cannot read that. [Edit] the original question and add it there formatted as code block (4 spaces indentation).

Comment: yes, i have updated it. the code does (1) and (2).
It copies the template and rename it accordingly.However i am still playing send the data from the source to the template since there is merge cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea which you can start with. It loops through the datas and for each data row it copies the template, renames it and fills in the data row into specific ranges.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AutoParseItems()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datas")

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A

    Const fRow As Long = 1 'set first data row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = fRow To lRow 'loop throug data rows
        'create a copy of the sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Dim wsNewTemplateCopy As Worksheet
        Set wsNewTemplateCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

        'determine new sheet name and rename the sheet
        With wsData.Cells(iRow, "A")
            wsNewTemplateCopy.Name = Right$(.Text, Len(.Text) - InStr(1, .Text, ":"))   'find : to determine new sheet name
        End With

        'fill in the text into the new sheet
        wsNewTemplateCopy.Range("A1").Value = wsData.Cells(iRow, "A").Value
        wsNewTemplateCopy.Range("A5").Value = wsData.Cells(iRow, "C").Value
        wsNewTemplateCopy.Range("A22").Value = wsData.Cells(iRow, "D").Value
            'modify the ranges where you need your data
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man for your assistance and help! 
I have just tested it and it does the job